# Using Apigen in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, apigen

I have been trying to use the Apigen script to do documentation in Netbeans. I downloaded Apigen.phar file and created the Apigen.bat file. I added the location of it into the Netbeans in the Apigen section. When I try to do the documentation for the project I get the error below:

***[InvalidArgumentException]

There are no commands defined in the "C" namespace.***

Any suggestions please.

P.S: I am using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

Create apigen.neon in your project folder and set it as "Configuration File" on "Project Properties"/"ApiGen" in Netbeans. Edit apigen.bat as is

```
@"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" "C:\xampp\php\apigen.phar" generate
```

It's not very good decision, but it's worked)